# Bug in my code using NSArray crashes

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm making a code which shows the names of people on a list.

The list is different for each date, so my problem is when there is only like 1 or no people signed and I make an array with index beyond the limit of people, it crashed. I know that this happens because the array is empty, but how do I make the code ignore empty arrays?

I have tried to make an "if" that count the number of arrays and then decide to post the array or just post no name. But it doesn't work like this, I still get the out of bounds exception.

How should I manage empty arrays?

My code:

```
NSString *html = [request2 responseString];
NSMutableArray *arr2 = [html componentsSeparatedByString:@"vagter"];
NSString *html1 = [arr2 objectAtIndex:1];

//name1
NSMutableArray *arr3 = [html1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"<td><font color=#ffffff>"];
NSString *html2 = [arr3 objectAtIndex:1];
NSMutableArray *arr4 = [html2 componentsSeparatedByString:@"</font></td>"];
NSString *html3 = [arr4 objectAtIndex:0];

_name.text = html3;

//name 2
NSMutableArray *arr5 = [html1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"<td><font color=#ffffff>"];

if ([arr5 count] > 4) {
    NSString *html4 = [arr5 objectAtIndex:5];
    NSMutableArray *arr6 = [html4 componentsSeparatedByString:@"</font></td>"];
    NSString *html5 = [arr6 objectAtIndex:0];

    _name.text = html5;
}
else
{
    _name1.text = @"No name";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
if ([arr5 count] > 5) {

    NSString *html4 = [arr5 objectAtIndex:5];
    ...
```

Indeed, index 5 will correspond to the sixth array item, so you have to have at least 6 objects in it.

Use the same pattern, if you want to check for the array bounds, in all cases.

Comment: you are so damn right ;D hmm sorry for stupid question then, I actually did put a lot of time in checking my code over and over again :P

Comment: don't worry: when you are stuck with something, usually it is with something that can be easily overseen... another couple of eyes can help...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you expect the return from componentsSeparatedByString to return consistent results according to your expectations.

Clearly thats not working.

Array handling is simple.  Dont ask for objects that arent there.

Check the count and only access indexes from 0 to count - 1;

If count is zero dont access anything.